# How to remove text from simple parentheses using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

**Problem:**
Text sample - `"Wanted String (unwanted)"`. There is only one string inside parentheses.

I need to remove the `"(unwanted)"` including parentheses using RegEx in PHP.

Comment: Something like `/\([^\)]+\)/` should do it.

Comment: Darren, you should grasp the concept of SO better. It's also a place where tired programmers can get to and get some help. Just read the most of the questions. "Research"??? I doubt here you will find a significant number fellows who couldn't solve problem with "research", especially SO type. Your downvote is unwelcome and misplaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/', '', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one pair of parentheses, you can use the following two regexes and then concatenate their result. For e.g., if your string is `Wanted String (unwanted) and something after it`, then:

- `[^\(]*` will return `Wanted String`. (Working example: https://regex101.com/r/vZ6eG4/1)
- `(?<=\)).*` will return `and something after it`. (Working example: https://regex101.com/r/wL3aO9/1)